# Android - Tracking User Clicks

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to implement a navigation bar for my app to track the user's selections as they move to different pages on the app.

For example, on a browser it would say:
`home screen -> Google -> "your search" -> next page visited etc.`

Through a little research, I found **Google Analytics** but not positive that's what I want. It seems like it should be relatively easy I just have not done anything like it before.

Any help?

Comment: adobe omniture analytics provide good results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google analytics or Flurry analytics. Both are good and very easy to use. Google it , there are lots of examples , sample codes.